# In Powershell get all text between 2 characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to collect all the text between 2 characters in a log file.

The example log file text is:

```
Conversation with Boris at 6/30/2017 7:26:35 AM on Server(jabber)
(7:26:41 AM) Boris@Boris.com/Server:  I likes cake
This was a Message from Boris to everyone at 2017-06-29 22:35:18.724681 EVE ~~~
```

I would like to collect all the text between the first bracket and the last tilde.

I have been trying to use REGEX to do this but am not sure of the correct pattern.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Allow the dot to match newlines: `'(?s)\(.*?~+'`

Comment: I got the string i provided wrong. Can someone help me with this string and a regex, please?

(9:39:40 AM) directorbot: We have a busy weekend ahead.

~~~ This was a broadcast from Boris to All at 2017-09-28 08:39:40.858803 EVE ~~~

From the first ( to the last ~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comment from wOxxOm, this regex pattern seems to do the trick: `'(?s)\(.*?~+'`

Here's how you can use it with PowerShell:

```
$Sample = @"
Conversation with Boris at 6/30/2017 7:26:35 AM on Server(jabber)
(7:26:41 AM) Boris@Boris.com/Server:  I likes cake
This was a Message from Boris to everyone at 2017-06-29 22:35:18.724681 EVE ~~~
"@

$Sample -Match '(?s)\(.*?~+' | Out-Null

$Result = $Matches.Values
```

Here's `$Result`:

```
(jabber)
(7:26:41 AM) Boris@Boris.com/Server:  I likes cake
This was a Message from Boris to everyone at 2017-06-29 22:35:18.724681 EVE ~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is so fixed that first '(' and last '~',I am giving you a easier looking solution without using Regex.Have a look at it

```
$x='Conversation with Boris at 6/30/2017 7:26:35 AM on Server(jabber)
(7:26:41 AM) Boris@Boris.com/Server:  I likes cake
This was a Message from Boris to everyone at 2017-06-29 22:35:18.724681 EVE ~~~'

$x.Substring($x.IndexOf('('),$x.IndexOf('~~~')-$x.IndexOf('(')+3)


 #Output
    (jabber)
    (7:26:41 AM) Boris@Boris.com/Server:  I likes cake
    This was a Message from Boris to everyone at 2017-06-29 22:35:18.724681 EVE ~~~
```

Hope this helps